# Finding Users with has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I have a `has_many through` relationship between the class `Conversation` and the class `User` through the class `Membership`.

I am trying to find all conversations where the user_id is equal to the `@current_user`.

I am struggling to find a simple answer but I answers usually point to something like this working.

```
 Conversation.includes(:users, :memberships).where('users_id = %s' @current_user.id)
```

I can't seem to find another way. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Something like `@current_user.memberships.map { |m| m.conversation }`? (haven't tested but should work if you have the relationships declared in your models.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If users has_many conversations through membership:

```
@current_user.conversations
```

This should return all conversations that is associated to current user through your membership model.

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association